# Is there an efficient algorithm to find which composition of boolean functions will match the output of a given boolean function?

Tags: algorithm, functional-programming, boolean, boolean-logic

Suppose I have the following boolean functions.

```
def Bottom():
    return False

def implies(var1, var2):
    if var1 == True and var2 == False: return False
    return True

def land(var1, var2):
    return var1 == True and var2 == True.
```

Is there an efficient algorithm which will take these three functions as input, and determine which (possibly multiple-application) functional composition of the first two functions will match the output of the third function for every Boolean (T,F) input to the third function?

I am using Python to write my example in, but I am not restricting solutions to Python or any programming language for that matter.
In fact I am not actually looking for code, but more of a description of an algorithm or an explanation for why one does not exist.

As a side note, my motivation for trying to discover this algorithm is because I was asked to show Functional Completeness of a particular set of logical connectives, and we do this by showing that one logical connective can be emulated by a certain set of others. 
For logic, we have to use a little bit of guess and check, but I could not figure out a way to capture that in a program without a linear search over a large space of possibilities.

Comment: reminds me of 3SAT (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem). May be reducible to it?

Comment: How are these functionally complete? How do you get `false`? Are you looking for something more efficient than exhaustive search (e.g., breadth-first search)?

Comment: @Patrick87, Yes, more efficient than exhaustive search. 
Also, thank you, I accidentally used an incomplete set instead of the complete set.

Comment: @Patrick87, Edited for correction.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map if you don't know the technique gives an algorithmic approach to finding a solution - albeit one which would be a pain to code.

Comment: Binary Decision Diagrams (BDDs) were developed to reduce the gate count in silicon-based logic. It should work for abstract logic, too. (there is a nice section on BDDs in Knuth 4a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only looking at boolean functions of two arguments, a simple brute-force technique will work. It could be extended to ternary logic, or ternary functions, or even both, but it is exponential so you can't push it too far. Here's the boolean version; I hope it's obvious how to extend it.

1) A binary boolean function is a relation `{False, True} X {False, True} -> {False, True}`. There are exactly 16 of these. Note that these include various functions which are independent of one or even both of the inputs. So let's make the set  consisting exactly of these 16 functions, and now note that every boolean function has a corresponding higher-order function  X  -> .

2) Now, start with the boolean functions `Take first` and `Take second`, and construct a closure using the HOFs corresponding to the "given functions". If the target function is in the closure, then it's achievable from some combination of the given functions. More generally, if every element in  is in the closure, then the given function(s) are universal.

So, let's apply this to your example. I'm going to write elements of  as a four-tuple corresponding to the inputs `(F,F) (F,T) (T,F) (T,T)` in that order, and I'm going to write the HOFs in **bold**. So `Bottom` is `FFFF` and `Implies` is `TTFT`. **Bottom**(a, b) is `FFFF` for any (a,b).

`Take first` is `FFTT` and `Take second` is `FTFT`, so that's our starting set. We can use **Bottom** to add `FFFF`, but obviously no further applications of **Bottom** are going to add anything.

So now we have nine possible pairs of functions we can apply to **Implies**. Here we go:

**Implies**(`FFTT`, `FFTT`) == `TTTT` (new)

**Implies**(`FFTT`, `FTFT`) == `TTFT` (new)

**Implies**(`FFTT`, `FFFF`) == `TTFF` (new)

**Implies**(`FTFT`, `FFTT`) == `TFTT` (new)

**Implies**(`FTFT`, `FTFT`) == `TTTT`

**Implies**(`FTFT`, `FFFF`) == `TFTF` (new)

**Implies**(`FFFF`, `FFTT`) == `TTTT`

**Implies**(`FFFF`, `FTFT`) == `TTTT`

**Implies**(`FFFF`, `FFFF`) == `TTTT`

Now we're up to eight of the sixteen functions, and we have a bunch more pairs to check. Since this is actually a complete set, it will get tedious, so I'll leave the next step to the reader (or perhaps their computer program).

Comment: This basic approach can be extended to functions of n > 2 variables, with 2^(2^n) bit vectors each of length 2^(n).